how to close a PDA token account
Now, I want to close a token account, but the owner of this token account is TOKEN_PROGRAM, so I cannot use the method below to close the account.
https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/src/anchor_lang/common.rs.html
this will error

At the same time, since I used InterfaceAccount, I cannot use Anchor's close constraint.


ok i find the solution , its very ez ,just use close_account function from anchor-spl
https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/token/fn.close_account.html
https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/token_2022/fn.close_account.html
